# Get Wait Time SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Activities( Type VARCHAR( 20 ),  Assigned_On DATETIME ,Status VARCHAR( 20 ) )
INSERT INTO Activities
VALUES
('Clerical','06/14/2016 11:30:00','Completed')
('Technical','06/14/2016 13:00:00','Completed')
('Clerical','06/14/2016 14:30:00','Completed')
('Technical','06/14/2016 16:00:00','Completed')
('Technical','06/14/2016 17:30:00','Completed')
('Technical','06/14/2016 19:00:00','Completed')
('Clerical','06/14/2016 20:30:00','Completed')
('Technical','06/14/2016 22:00:00','Completed')
('Technical','06/14/2016 23:30:00','Completed')
('Clerical','06/15/2016 01:00:00','Completed')
('Technical','06/15/2016 02:30:00','In Progress')
('Clerical','06/15/2016 04:00:00','In Progress')
('Technical','06/15/2016 05:30:00','In Progress')
('Technical','06/15/2016 07:00:00','In Progress')
('Clerical','06/15/2016 08:30:00','Completed')
('Clerical','06/15/2016 10:00:00','Completed')
('Technical','06/15/2016 11:30:00','Completed')
('Clerical','06/15/2016 13:00:00','Completed')
('Technical','06/15/2016 14:30:00','Completed')
('Technical','06/15/2016 16:00:00','In Progress')
('Technical','06/15/2016 17:30:00','In Progress')
('Clerical','06/15/2016 17:39:00','Waiting')
('Technical','06/15/2016 17:48:00','Completed')
('Technical','06/15/2016 17:57:00','In Progress')
('Clerical','06/15/2016 18:06:00','Waiting')
('Clerical','06/15/2016 18:15:00','Waiting')
('Technical','06/15/2016 18:24:00','Completed')
('Clerical','06/15/2016 18:33:00','Completed')
('Clerical','06/15/2016 18:42:00','In Progress')
('Technical','06/15/2016 18:51:00','In Progress')
('Technical','06/15/2016 19:00:00','Waiting')
('Clerical','06/15/2016 19:09:00','Waiting')
('Technical','06/15/2016 19:18:00','Waiting')
```

and would like to get summary of wait times

```
Declare @datetimenow datetime
SET @datetimenow = GetDate()  -- or some date time to use for testing

Select Count(Type) datediff(Minute, Assigned_On, @datetimenow) where status = 'Waiting'
```

But need it grouped and tabulated by type with number of people waiting and highest wait time for each type, such that result looks like

```
Type      People Waiting      Wait Time (Minutes)
Clerical        5                     11:08
Technical       5                     15:38
```

Any ideas how?

thanks

Comment: Please explain how you calculate "wait times" with the data you have provided.  The logic is not clear.

Comment: using the datediff function, find the earliest waiting datetime for each time and subtract from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question but the code will give an idea:

```
SELECT Type, Count(*) as 'People Waiting', 
    CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,GetDate(), MIN(Assigned_On) ) / 60 as varchar)
    + ':' + CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,GetDate(), MIN(Assigned_On) ) % 60 as varchar)
    as 'Wait Time (Minutes)'
FROM Activities
WHERE Status = 'Waiting' 
GROUP BY Type;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, think about how you would go about finding the 'waiting people' and their wait times.  I imagine something like this:

```
SELECT Type, datediff(minutes, Assigned_on, getdate()) AS WaitMinutes
FROM Activities
WHERE Status = 'Waiting'
```

Now it should be obvious, but you just use `COUNT(*)` to get the count and `MAX(WaitMinutes)` to get the maximum wait time, right?  If you don't want to do this in a `WITH`, just use the formula to group by:

```
SELECT Type,
    COUNT(*) AS PeopleWaiting,
    MAX(datediff(minutes, Assigned_On, getdate())) AS MaxWaitMinutes
FROM Activities
WHERE Status = 'Waiting'
GROUP BY Type
```

Comment: Don't need the where as you want all types.  I have removed my answer, I forgot the group by on duration

Comment: Don't you want the people waiting?

Comment: why would you group by the difference? that is incorrect. @Mike..your answer is better than this one.

Comment: Right, I misplaced that and forgot to remove it when I added it to the select